# Attempting to generate 3D plot from 2D (1039 x 1392) Array

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I'm trying to convert a .asc file into a 3D graph. I used pandas to import the file and create an array, which my terminal lists to be (1039 x 1392)

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_table('[data´s location on the disk]')
print data 

nx, ny = 1392, 1039
x = range(nx)
y = range(ny)
hf = plt.figure()
ha = hf.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)  
ha.plot_surface(X,Y,data,rstride=1,cstride=1)

plt.show()
```

when i run this, it doesn't generate any errors, but simply opens up a new figure window which remains blank but then requires a force quit due to non-responsiveness when I try to close it. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: maybe you just need to wait longer; matplotlib is really not very well-performing, and plotting a million-point surface will take roughly forever.

Comment: If you know the data is well-behaved (ie. doesn't change from one point to another too much), consider low-pass (aka anti-aliasing) filtering it and then only using every Nth point in both dimensions

Comment: try making the data into an array first.

Comment: and can you please post a reproducible example?

Comment: increasing the rstride and cstride seemed to do the trick, i.e. they reduced the wait time to something reasonable.